# SVG Storage and Manipultion

Tags: image, svg, amazon-s3, canvas

So I am trying to make a system that will allow you to upload SVG images and then choose settings to display the selected SVG file in different colors and sizes over a specified background. Basically you can choose different backgrounds and then select an SVG, size,  and color to be displayed on top of that background

Currently I am just storing the SVG file in the database as Text and using RegEx to look for fill colors and replace with currentColor so I can change the SVG color with CSS.

Is there anyway I can store these images in s3 and then call them and still be able to influence the fill color?

Also what would be the best way to display and modify the sized of these SVG's? I'm assuming using  <canvas> is probably going to be the best bet. Trying to plan this out and am wondering if anyone has any suggestions or knows of packages/functions/css attributes, that may be helpful.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: You can use SVG filters to recolor images - might be a bit simpler